# rails - nginx + puma - static assets not being served by nginx from the tutorial link provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

I am using Ubuntu. 
Here is the [tutorial](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-setup-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx/)

Nginx config I am using:

```
upstream my_app {
server unix:///home/uname/railsproject/my_app.sock;
}

server {
listen 88; #(I used exact 88 when I am testing now)
server_name localhost; # I used exact localhost when I am testing this
root /home/uname/railsproject/public; # I assume your app is located at that location

location / {
 proxy_pass http://my_app; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

location ~* ^/assets/ {
 # Per RFC2616 - 1 year maximum expiry
 expires 1y;
 add_header Cache-Control public;

 # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
 # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
 # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
 add_header Last-Modified "";
 add_header ETag "";
 break;
 }
```

}

Puma command

```
RAILS_ENV=production puma -e production  -b unix:///home/uname/railsproject/my_app.sock -p 8000
```

In the address bar, I am typing

```
http://localhost/
```

and then website opening but static assets not working. Of course, I ran

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

and assets are available in public/assets folder
I also tried placing `m.txt` file in assets directory and accessing

```
http://localhost/assets/m.txt
```

but didn't work. I also tried this command:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data public/
```

but this didn't help.

Comment: Is it possible that something else is running on port `80`?  It looks like your `nginx` is listening on port `88` but you're testing on port `80` by doing `http://localhost/assets/m.txt`

Comment: localhost:88 is working, thanks, I thought I need to access using localhost, anyway, thanks.

Comment: did you end up finding a solution?

Answer (score 19):

I'm posting for future readers.
I encounter this error when I change my hosting provider. My standard nginx conf for assets stop working, I have to change it for:

```
location ~ ^assets/ 
    {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }
```

Removing the / before /assets did the trick, don't know why. 
ps: location is in the server block

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem. I got an answer from the very helpful #nginx channel on irc. They said it was "idiomatic nginx" and that the other form, though more popular, was discouraged:

```
server {
  server_name server.com;

  # path for static files
  root /home/production/server.com/current/public;

  location / {
      try_files $uri @proxy;
      # if url path access by directory name is wanted:
      #try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
  }

  location @proxy {
      proxy_pass  http://localhost:9292;
      proxy_set_header Host      $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

/hattip: vandemar

Comment: Where does the upstream directive and socket address go? The config he copied from the tutorial start like:   

server unix:///home/uname/railsproject/my_app.sock;