# How to serve webpacked assets of Rails app in Elastic Beanstalk container?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using Rails5 app and deployed it to EB container successfully.

But webpacked assets -- served in `public/packs` directly, return 404 in production environment.

In current situation, I set `RAILS_SKIP_ASSET_COMPILATION = false` so I precompile assets before deploying the app everytime.

I used to use heroku as a production environment and everything went ok at that time.

here is my `config/webpacker.yml`:

```
source_path: app/frontend/javascripts
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_output_path: packs # public/packs/filename-[hash].js
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  extensions:
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg
```

### what I tried...

I tried to change public_output_path from packs to assets. but same error persists...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well. I'm not sure if you're using Nginx or Passenger. But if it's Nginx you'll probably want to add a location block to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp_healthd.conf` that looks like this:

```
location /packs {
  alias /var/app/current/public/packs;
  gzip_static on;
  gzip on;
  expires max;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

Then run `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart`.

That should be enough to get it working. But you'll want to create a `.ebextensions/` file in your project with these custom settings so it doesn't get overwritten by the Elastic Beanstalk default config.

See [this post](https://medium.com/@marilu597/getting-to-know-and-love-aws-elastic-beanstalk-configuration-files-ebextensions-9a4502a26e3c) by Maria Luisa Carrion D. to see how to automate the nginx config.

Comment: If you use the Amazon Linux 2 EB Platform, the answer here is the recommended approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69103413/1852005

Answer (score 0):

With the Amazon Linux 2 Elastic Beanstalk Platform, this is now a whole lot easier.

The default config for nginx is located here `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` which you can see if you `eb ssh` to your server.

There is a line of code in the `server {...}` block which says:

```
# Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;
```

This include is there so you can easily include additional location rules for your server. All you have to do in your app is create a `.platform` folder in your root directory if you haven't already, and create a config file with this path: `.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/10_packs_location.conf`
("10_packs_location" can be any name you want).

Put in these file contents:

```
location /packs {
  alias /var/app/current/public/packs;
  gzip_static on;
  gzip on;
  expires max;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

And then upon your next deployment, you'll see your new "10_packs_location.conf" file under `/etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/`, which will be included by `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.
With this complete, the new location rule will have applied.

See documentation here for more details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to have Rails itself serve the assets instead of NGINX.

in your `config/environments/production.rb` you probably have the following:

```rb
# Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
# Apache or NGINX already handles this.
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV["RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES"].present?
```

If you set the `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES = enabled` in you AWS EB, Rails will serve the assets.

This is the default behaviour in Heroku:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/617

Here is a nice post about it:
https://acuments.com/rails-serve-static-files-with-nginx.html

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to get around all of this without messing with Elasticbeanstalk is to change your webpacker.yml file to use assets/packs instead of packs which is already being served correctly.

```
production:
  <<: *default

  # Production requires the packs folder to be in assets for nginx
  public_output_path: assets/packs
```